# How can I pass command line input to external process in Unix

Tags: unix, command-line, input, fork

My program runs(exec..) an external program.
While running, the external program asks user [Yes/No] to proceed next step.

Instead of typing [yes] in command line, how can I pass [Yes] to the external program from my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the external program supports a respective flag (see @Jonathan Leffler's answer), your you have control over that program's source and can add it, you have to simulate the "yes" input.

Options:

- Try launching the external program by piping the output of the [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) helper application to it's stdin: `yes | external_program`. `yes` is a simple tool, should you not have it, that just writes "y" to it's stdout continually.
- Manually write "yes" to to stdin of the external program.

Both options require your to use pipes in one way or the other. See [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg29197.html) for more information on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to provide a 'yes' response on the command line is a `-y` option (usually with a parallel `-n` option to indicate a 'no' — see `fsck(1)`).

There's also room to argue that running the program should be a 'yes, I mean to do it' operation.  However, there are times when it makes sense to specify 'yes, I really mean to do it' (such as one-time initialization of an instance of a DBMS).